# Compare Function result to multiple values

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm redesigning some of my For-loops to run faster. Especially the ones that call functions to compare values with. I'm wondering if my basic Delphi knowledge is missing something really useful.

I have a lot of For-loops similar to this:

```
for i :=1 to 10000 do
  begin
    //---  Check if Condition for each Object (i) Property = Yes, Y or a Number  --- 
    if (fGetPropValue(i,'Condition')='Yes') Or (fGetPropValue(i,'Condition')='Y') Or (StrToIntDef(fGetPropValue(i,'Condition'),0)>0)
    then
      // code...

  end;
```

In this case function gets called 3 times, if result is different than Yes or Y. If it's Yes, it's only called once and skips the rest of calls.

I can use single call and store value to variable, like this:

```
for i :=1 to 10000 do
begin
  //---  Get Condition for each Object (i) Property   ---
  vCondition:=fGetPropValue(i,'Condition');
  //---  Check Condition = Yes, Y or a number  ---
  if (vCondition='Yes') Or (vCondition='Y') Or (StrtoIntDef(vCondition,0)>0)
  then
    // code...

end;
```

This is good, but what in case where I need to compare more complex, like:

```
for i :=1 to 10000 do
  begin

    if (fGetPropValue(i,'Condition')='Yes') Or (fGetPropValue(i,'Condition')='Y') Or (StrtoIntDef(fGetPropValue(i,'Condition'),0)>0) And
       (fGetPropValue(i,'Enabled')='Yes') Or (fGetPropValue(i,'Enabled')='Y') Or (StrtoIntDef(fGetPropValue(i,'Enabled'),0)>0) And
       (fGetPropValue(i,'Visible')='Yes') Or (fGetPropValue(i,'Visible')='Y') Or (StrtoIntDef(fGetPropValue(i,'Visible'),0)>0) And
       (fGetPropValue(i,'AllowAccess')='Yes') Or (fGetPropValue(i,'AllowAccess')='Y') Or (StrtoIntDef(fGetPropValue(i,'AllowAccess'),0)>0)
    then
      // code...

  end;
```

In this case if I introduce 4 variable and get all 4 values, I eliminate the speedy option if first logical comparison is true - without 4 variable it will not execute anymore calls.

**Any way to redesign complex comparison?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract this into a function that you can re-use:

```
function PropValueIsTrue(const PropValue: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PropValue='Yes') or (PropValue='Y') or (StrtoIntDef(PropValue,0)>0);
end;
```

Then your code becomes:

```
if PropValueIsTrue(fGetPropValue(i,'Condition')) and
   PropValueIsTrue(fGetPropValue(i,'Enabled')) and
   PropValueIsTrue(fGetPropValue(i,'Visible')) and
   PropValueIsTrue(fGetPropValue(i,'AllowAccess')) then
```

Comment: Having seen quite a lot of your code recently, it's clear that this sort of re-factoring is not part of your toolkit. It's the most important of all the refactorings, and your code will be far better once you master it. You will benefit in many ways. Your code will be more readable and so easier to maintain. Your code will be less prone to copy/paste errors, what I refer to as *inheriting from the clipboard*. I recommend you read this: http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html

Comment: Looking back over your code, it's clear that you can spot patterns that are amenable to extraction, but that you don't contemplate extracting. Your instinct is to retain all your code in one large do it all method. Once you get familiar with decomposing and extracting, you'll look back over your old code and wince!

Comment: Great! Didn't think about this approach.

Comment: You're right on your observation. 9 years of copy & paste of approaches 'that work'. Now, working on improving this. Thank you for the resource link.

Comment: They work right up until the point where you want to change behaviour, and then you pretty much have to review your entire code base. We've all been there! ;-)